# Samsung Galaxy S2 GT-I91000 OEM driver?

Tags: android, galaxy, samsung-mobile

It look like there is no driver for this model here http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads ? Where can i get the driver from so i can run my eclipse-developed android apps on my phone?

Comment: u are using windows or linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running Windows, you should install Kies (software from samsung). That software installs the driver you need. Then, eclipse will recognise your phone. Remember to install the Android-Eclipse plugin from Google developers.

Answer (score 0):

Install Kies(software from samsung) and also in case check for usb driver in sdk manager and download it..